# Is using trim on a ssd with LVM LUKS safe?

Tags: encryption, aes, disk-encryption, luks

I know that it can allow an attacker to know the filesystem and file size, but can it allow an attacker to decrypt any files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand about the information betrayed by observing results of TRIM operations on LUKS encrypted volumes, actual plain-text data is not likely to be recovered. As you say, filesystem and data layout information can be inferred. Rather, details on the crypto implementation could help an attacker reduce the key space in a brute-force attack.

Conversely, there are security implications from **not** enabling TRIM where if your passphrase is compromised and you decide to re-encrypt the header, there is no guarentee the original header is overwritten. This would mean that later attainment of your disk could mean an attacker using the compromised password could forensically locate the old encrypted header, get the master password and decrypt data despite the change of passphrase. I would consider this scenario more of a concern for the average user than a third-party being able to forensically determine where unused blocks are and/or the filesystem.

A great analysis of the kind of information and other concerns regarding TRIM implementation on dm-crypt'ed devices can be found here:

http://asalor.blogspot.co.uk/2011/08/trim-dm-crypt-problems.html

Comment: How far would the key space for a brute-force attack be reduced? Would it be any smaller then the key space for using aes over the wire sending just the important data no noise?

Comment: @user it would not necessarily be reduced, but it would give the attacker more confidence on what the algorithm in use was. If they did not know it was only AES-128, they might be trying to brute-force the AES-256 key space, for example.

Comment: TRIM is not related at all, you old header can be stored in old cell with and without TRIM. To be sure that header is cleaned you need to write all empty space of your drive, even after that your header can be areas which remapped by controller. So compromising - requires changing of encryption keys - re-encryption.